# Have Entity Framework ignore derived types

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

in my current project I'm using code first approach.

I have a type called `Task` which is part of the model. I also have `BackgroundTask` derived from `Task` and `UserAccountTask` derived from `BackgroundTask`.

When I simply try to create an object of type `Task` and add it to my task repository, I get a `DbUpdateException` as soon as I try to save the changes to the db. Its inner exception states:

> "Invalid column name 'UserAccount_UserId'.\r\nInvalid column name 'UserAccount_Lastname'.\r\nInvalid column name 'UserAccount_Firstname'.\r\nInvalid column name 'UserAccount_Fullname'.\r\nInvalid column name 'UserAccount_Password'.\r\nInvalid column name 'UserAccount_Title'[...]"

`UserAccount` is another type and a property of `UserAccountTask` (`UserId`, `Lastname` etc. are properties of `UserAccount`).

I hope my description of the problem isn't too messed up :-/
I just want EF to ignore the fact that `Task` is the base class for some other type because IMHO it doesn't matter at that time.

Thanks in advance, Kevin

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to use this in your derived context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Ignore<UserAccountTask>();
    modelBuilder.Ignore<BackgroundTask>();
}
```